# Read value from kendo dropdownlistfor mvc5

Tags: .net, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-5, dropdownlistfor

I have a Create View in razor where im saving my selected value from kendo DropDownListFor and its working great. Problem is on edit page when i want to have this value as selected. Its showing me only default value but its in a model. Here's my code

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.Client.Country)                         
                      .MinLength(3)
                      .Filter("contains") 
                    .BindTo(EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(Country)))
```

Answer (score 0):

While editing you have to assign the selected value to your model propertie, 
any way while edit/load partial view you need to get the data from controller in action method bind the selected value to  as below

model.Client.Country = "your selected value"